# Assert URL using PHP Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium 2 Webdriver written by [Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver)

I am trying to check if the current URL is equal to a hardcoded URL but my code doesnt work:

> $driver->wait(3)->until(
>
> ```
> WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(             
>             $url = $driver->getCurrentURL();
>
>             if($url == 'http://myurl.com')
>                     {
>                        echo 'yes correct url';
>                     }
>     )
> ```
>
> );

Comment: what does getCurrentUrl() return actually? I suspect, it returns 'http://myurl.com/' instead 'http://myurl.com'

Answer (score 0):

We can use php closure function to create a complex condition if it is not included in WebDriverExpectedCondition. Here is the way to do so.

```
$driver->wait(3)->until(function ($driver) {
  return $driver->getCurrentURL() === 'http://myurl.com';
})
```